# how to implement Server Side Sorting on Server Side Pagination using RDT?

Tags: server-side-rendering, react-data-table-component

i am making and application in nextjs using React Data Table to show data post data from db..

i have implemented server side pagination on RDT and also have implemented the Descending order sort.
i have set the Rows per page default to "10" okay!
 as you see below on the initial page 10 items are fetch and is also being sorted in descending order in the ui..

```
page 1 data
0: {id: 144}
1: {id: 148}
2: {id: 150}
3: {id: 152}
4: {id: 103}
5: {id: 140}
6: {id: 143}
7: {id: 147}
8: {id: 149}
9: {id: 151}
```

but as soon as the `data.lenght > 10` it doesnt show in the initial page rather it gets transferred to the next page and the RDT in not sorted according to the new data...

```
page 2 latest data
when data > 10 it gets transferred to next page
0: {id: 153}
```

is there any solution to this ? it would be very helpful...

```
these are the sorting props i am passing...
defaultSortAsc={false}
defaultSortFieldId="dateCreated"
```

i have tried client side sorting but dont know how to implement server side sorting in RDT